# Layout folders android

Tags: android, android-layout

Are there any different layout folders for different screen resolutions for portrait and landscape view? Which folder for which screen size in pixels is used?

Answer (score 2):

There are different layout folders for different screen pixel densities and orientations. Here are some examples:

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation
```

to know more about this check the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

```
xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp
```

Comment: These folders for which screen resolution meet?

Answer (score -1):

have you tried looking at [the Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) provided by Google? its usually a good start for questions like this.

the tl;dr of it is yes, there are different layout folders for different screen resolutions (denoted by the `layout-` prefix, with the DPI buckets ranging from `layout-ldpi` to `layout-xxxhdpi`)

you can also add the suffix `-land` to a folder to denote a landscape layout folder, ie `layout-hdpi-land`